# Rails 3 Need help with next month on a calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

is it possible to advance a variable something like `@current_month = Date.today.month+1` then forward it back to the index page, if so how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@current_month = Date.today + 1.month
```

Not sure quite what you mean by 'forward it back to the index page', but if you then

```
render :action => 'index'
```

the `@current_month` instance variable will be available to the index view of that controller. You could print out the month only by using strftime, eg `<%= @current_month.strftime("%B") %>`

Check out `.strftime` at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392

Comment: that might be what im looking for i will let ya know if it worked!

Answer (score 2):

For calendar operations, one probably wants to start at the beginning of the month.

```
@current_month = 1.month.from_now.beginning_of_month
```

This will return a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object which is similar to Ruby's `DateTime`.

OR

```
@current_month = Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.next_month
```

which will return a Ruby `Date` object.